# How to return a Task and use to update the progressbar in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to update a `ProgressBar` that is added to a separate Stage in `javafx`. I have defined task in a method named `messagemerge()` and a new thread containing this task is called from there. Each time i try to use the task that is returned by the method `messagemerge()` to the main, it throws a `NullPointerException`

This is what i have tried

```
ProgressBarDialog progressBarDialog=new ProgressBarDialog();
Task<Void> task=messageMerge();
progressBarDialog.progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
```

The above code is written in the main

The method `messageMerge()` is as defined below

```
public Task<Void> messageMerge() throws Exception
{
  task=new Task<Void>(){
  protected Void call()throws Exception{
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    updateProgress(i,50);
    }
    return null;
    };
  Thread thread=new Thread(task);
  thread.start();
  return task;
}
```

The `progessBarDialog` is another class defined as below

```
public class ProgressBarDialog {
public ProgressBar progressBar=null;
public ProgressBarDialog()
{
    Stage progressDialog=new Stage();
    progressDialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    ProgressBar progressBar=new ProgressBar();
    progressBar.setProgress(0);

    BorderPane progressPane=new BorderPane();
    progressPane.setCenter(progressBar);
    progressDialog.setScene(new Scene(progressPane,500,100));
    progressDialog.show();

}
```

`NullPointerException` occurs when i try to access `task.progressProperty()` from the main. Could someone please help me on this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*What is Wrong*

It is just a logic error, you aren't initializing the progressBar member variable and it is always null. When you try to use the progressBar member, you get a NullPointerException.

Essentially, you are ["shadowing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class) the progressBar variable by redeclaring it in a different scope, so your original variable is never assigned a value.

*How to Fix*

To fix this issue, replace the following line:

```
ProgressBar progressBar=new ProgressBar()
```

with:

```
progressBar=new ProgressBar()
```

*Not related, but suspicious code in your sample*

Incidentally, the task usage in your messageMerge function also looks suspicious, you should probably be declaring the task locally to your method (though that is unlikely to be the source of your NullPointerException).  massageMerge is returning a task, so you usually don't need to set a class member variable to the same value from within the function (because your invoking code can just use the value returned from the massageMerge function).

Instead of:

```
task=new Task<Void>() { ...
```

You probably want:

```
Task<Void> task=new Task<>() { ...
```

*Alternate implementations*

You don't need to code a ProgressDialog yourself, you can use the [Makery progress dialog example based on only the JavaFX APIs](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-dialogs/), or you can use the third party [ControlsFX ProgressDialog](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org).

*Take care to set window ownership correctly for Modality*

Either way, you probably want to pay attention to [Window Modality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866432/controls-fx-progress-dialog-modality-alert-modality).

Comment: Thanks a lot. i thought the problem was with the Task.